# Determining a function is harmonic from mean value property for just three(?) radii.

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis

This theorem is well-known (maybe it can be called Morera's theorem):

> A continuous function satisfying the mean value property on balls is harmonic.

I was recently surprised to hear in a talk that the conclusion still holds if you only check the mean value property on three (I think) radii. I also can't remember if this should refer to the mean value taken on the interior or boundary of the balls (if it matters at all). Does anyone have a reference or name for this theorem? I would enjoy seeing the details and a proof.

Comment: I've posted this on MO [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244048/determining-a-function-is-harmonic-from-mean-value-property-for-just-three-ra).