# Prove that a function is harmonic if in every point $x$ it suffices mean value property for some sequence of balls $B(x, r_j), r_j\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

**TASK:** Prove that a function $u\in C(\Omega)$ is harmonic if in every point $x \in \Omega$ it suffices mean value property $$u(x) = \frac{1}{|\partial B(x, r_j)|} \int_{\partial B(x, r_j)} u \, \text{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$$ for some sequence of balls $B(x, r_j)$ for descending sequence of radii s.t. $ r_j\rightarrow 0$.

**NOTICE:** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853774/determining-a-function-is-harmonic-from-mean-value-property-for-just-three-ra) question suggests that it would work even with a finite number of radii, but the theory required to prove it is too complicated (since the task was given within an introductory PDE class) and distant from the initial task.

**MY ATTEMPT:** I was trying to prove by contradiction by assuming that $$\exists x \in \Omega \, \exists r > 0 : u(x) \neq \frac{1}{|\partial B(x, r)|} \int_{\partial B(x, r)} u \, \text{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$$
and taking $r_j<r$ and constructing a function $v$ that satisfies

$$\begin{cases} \Delta v = 0 &\text{on } B(x,r_j) \\ v = u &\text{on } \partial B(x,r_j) \end{cases}$$ thus getting a function $v$ such that:

- $\Delta v = 0$;
- $u(x)=v(x)$ (thanks to mean-value property on the boundary);
- $\forall r_j < r : \int_{\partial B(x, r_j)} u \, \text{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1} = \int_{\partial B(x, r_j)} v \, \text{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$.

And yet still I couldn't see how to extrapolate the mean-value property on $\partial B(x,r)$ of $v$ onto $u$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of an approach: To keep things simple, suppose $u$ has the sequence mean value property in some $B(0,R), R>1.$ Try to show $u$ is harmonic in $B(0,1)$ by looking at $u-v,$ where $v$ is the Poisson integral of $u$ restricted to the unit sphere. The idea is to show $u=v.$ We already know $u=v$ on the unit sphere. If $u-v>0$ somewhere, then $u-v$ has a positive max $M$ somewhere in $B(0,1).$ Choose a point closest to the unit sphere where $u-v=M.$ You should run into a problem there ...